# Dropdown using javascript onchange doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a simple drop down and I want to have it so that if the user selects "STUDENT", it will display Student data from mysql. But the page stays the same (it show's the "STUDENT" for one second and back to the original page),and this isn't working. Can someone please help.

Below is my code:

```
<th width="20%">View&nbsp;Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="form1">
            <select  name="value1" onchange="document.forms.form1.submit();">
                    <option value="all">All('.$count.')</option>
                    <option value="student">STUDENT('.$stucount.')</option>
                    <option value="faculty">FACULTY('.$facount.')</option>
               </select>  

 </form>       
    </tr>
';
```

Comment: Replace `$_post` with `$_POST`

Comment: document.form.form1.submit()

Comment: (For one thing) Change this `if (!isset($_post['value1'])||$_POST['value1']== 'all')` to `if (!isset($_POST['value1'])||$_POST['value1']== 'all')` `$_POST` is a [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and MUST be in uppercase.

Comment: Giving the "why", is always beneficial. @vee ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you're right.  Thanks for the punch :).  Your first comment converted to an answer should close this issue.

Comment: You're welcome. However, questions like these, and I take this from experience, usually end up in opening up a "can of worms", which in this case, I've hit the nail right on head (again). As seen from OP's comment(s) in the answer below. Cheers @vee

Comment: You've obviously been down `"that road"` before ;-) @vee

Comment: Thank you it works, but after I changed it, when I select "STUDENT", it display student data but the drop down menu still shows "ALL". Second, When I select "ALL" back , the page doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the answer posted by [Awlad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359721/2513523) try this for your second problem. Your code is not complete by the way, so before you echo the above form place this:

`$value = (isset($_POST['value1'])) ? $_POST['value1'] : '';`

And replace with this:

```
<th width="20%">View&nbsp;Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="form1">
            <select  name="value1" onchange="document.forms.form1.submit();">
                    <option value="all"'.($value=="all"?"selected":"").'>All('.$count.')</option>
                    <option value="student"'.($value=="student"?"selected":"").'>STUDENT('.$stucount.')</option>
                    <option value="faculty"'.($value=="faculty"?"selected":"").'>FACULTY('.$facount.')</option>
               </select>  

 </form>       
    </tr>
';
```

`$value` saves the POST value sent, once you click on the dropdown and based on that value, the respective option will  be selected.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<select  name="value1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

all `$_post` should be `$_POST`.

`$_POST` is a super global variable and all variables in php are case sensitive.

Set post data in your option and check the post data and set select one option.
Try this :

```
<select  name="value1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option <?php echo (isset($_POST['value1']) && $_POST['value1'] == 'all')? 'selected="selected"' :  ''; ?> value="all">All('.$count.')</option>
            <option <?php echo (isset($_POST['value1']) && $_POST['value1'] == 'student')? 'selected="selected"' :  ''; ?>  value="student">STUDENT('.$stucount.')</option>
            <option <?php echo (isset($_POST['value1']) && $_POST['value1'] == 'faculty')? 'selected="selected"' :  ''; ?> value="faculty">FACULTY('.$facount.')</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *"all $_post should be $_POST"* --- Ok, why?

Comment: @Fred-ii- He is right. PHP variables are case-sensitive and that goes for the reserved variable `$_POST` too.

Comment: You think I don't know that? [Here, read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359695/dropdown-using-javascript-onchange-doesnt-work#comment32207053_21359695) @user007 - People obviously don't bother reading comments.

Comment: Whoops! Missed reading that one. And maybe people can be a little more specific of what they want.

Comment: That's why when people post answers with nothing to backup their answer with (facts), doesn't help anyone, and mostly the OP in this case. Had the OP known the "why", then that mistake would've been avoided. ;-) @user007

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have added descriptions with my answer

Comment: It's actually called a [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) (Just a quick FYI) ;-) @AwladLiton - You can use that in your answer if you want to, you have my blessing. ;-)

Comment: Thank you it works, but after I changed it, when I select "STUDENT", it display student data but the drop down menu still shows "ALL". Second, When I select "ALL" back , the page doesn't change

Comment: @Sio: you have submit form so page is reloading. so it will not select the selected value in dropdown

Comment: @AwladLiton Is there anyway to not reloading the page but still show different data?